# get all build from a label to next available label for a branch

Tags: powershell, tfs, tfsbuild, azure-devops-rest-api, tfvc

do we have any rest api that can have takes labels as an argument and return all the builds for check in between tow labels

the TFS version I am using is Team foundation server 2015

I have no clue how to start this

my requirement is to get all check-in for a particular release, we generally create a label for RC branch whenever we create a feature branch for new release

Comment: Welcome to SO. Have you been using TFVC or GIT for version control in TFS2015? Could you please share some screenshots to help explain your current workflow and expectations? Thx.